# Unit testing property modifier

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, tdd

I'm talking about Typescript but it could be a generic question...

How to test that a property is readonly?

I mean, it's a language feature so seems quite obvious that if I declare a property as readonly no one can reassign it as the code won't compile, but without any test, no one assure me that I can safely change the code, make the property writable and then modify it...
So how can I write a unit test that fails if the property is writable?

Comment: You would need to implement a runtime check to do that, since typescripts readonly is only during compile time. During runtime it indeed is writable. So without modifying the code, you can't unit test that. Also, you usually don't want to unit test this. Rather test the behavior of your external interface of your class and try not to depend on the internal state during testing as much as possible.

Comment: "Unit tests" are not the only tool we have to ensure the quality of our work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can* you write such a test? Yes; using plain javascript that calls the javascript code your Typescript code transpiles to.

However, *should* you write such a test?
No.

One of the main reasons to use transpiled and/or compiled languages such Typescript is that the compiler takes on part of the burden of correctness. Specifically, the correctness of the guarantees the language offers.

So sit back and enjoy the heavy lifting the compiler does for you.

One caveat: If your project uses a mix of javascript and Typescript then you *might* want to consider it, but then it is still probably better to spend that time rewriting the javascript bits to Typescript.

Edit:
Look at the situation from the perspective of the test: what would be necessary for the test to pass *now* and fail *at some later time* due to regression?
Well, since the code won't compile if some later edit modifies the `readonly` property, this edit must include removing the `readonly` from the property.
But having seen and rejected this guard, what is to stop the editor from removing the test that now fails as well?

So in a sense, the `readonly` modifier *is* the test.

Comment: sure, and this is exactly what I think. As it is a language feature I can leave the compiler to ensure no one can modify the property.

My concern is about the possibility to remove the readonly property. The compiler can avoid changing the property, but can't avoid deleting the keyword to be able to modify it. And I suppose that the immutability it's a "requested feature". How to reflect this into the code? Normally all features are ensured by tests, but for this kind of thing which is the best approach?

Comment: I understand your concern. I've edited the answer to address that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also going to test if other properties are private or public? Don't follow that road. It is a clear case of over-testing.